How to pass ref to props?
I have a ref that should be passed to props, but when I do so ref is undefined in child component
parent.vue
<div ref="target">target</div>
<cmp :target="$refs.target" />

cmp.vue
mounted() {
  console.log("target:", this.target); // undefined
}

Example: codesandbox
after hot module replacement target is correct

I recommend to use another event/data flow like emitting an event from cmp then handle it in parent by targeting the parent elements

Refs aren't reactive, at least in v2, you could make it work by mounting  later. This is XY problem, should be done as described above.

From the docs: "An important note about the ref registration timing: because the refs themselves are created as a result of the render function, you cannot access them on the initial render - they don’t exist yet!". As EstusFlask suggested, you can mount the cmp when target ref is registered with v-if="$refs.target".

I guess this link is relevant as a whole here. But yes, use Vue2's $refs sparingly with considerations regarding its limitations.

I am not sure about passing it as a prop, but you can always do that in the child component.
console.log(this.$parent.$refs.target);

More info in the docs.

Here is the alternative way of doing things (indeed more clean).
App.vue
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div ref="target">target</div>
    <cmp :getScreenRef="() => $refs['target']" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Cmp from "./components/cmp.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Cmp,
  },
};
</script>

cmp.vue
<template>
  <div>
    qwe <br />
    <button @click="logTarget">click me</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      screenRef: "",
    };
  },
  props: {
    getScreenRef: {
      type: Function,
      default: () => ({}),
    },
  },
  methods: {
    logTarget() {
      console.log("target:", this.screenRef);
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.screenRef = this.getScreenRef();
    this.$nextTick(function () {
      console.log("here?", this.screenRef);
    });
  },
};
</script>

Credits to this answer.

As an option. To make child component reusable, ofc it possible to get string with name of ref in props. But it looks like really bad solution.

Relying on $parent is a bad practice that was inherited from angular 1.x

Using refs is usually a sign of hacking if not used for specific cases anyway, but I agree. Also, Vue2 refs are not reactive and makes it even less relevant.
